# How do I get the color data of 3 points in my sprite kit game?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cgimage

I'm trying to simulate a line-following robot in a 2d swift game.

Now here's a screenshot of what it looks like so far: [image: screenshot]

The yellow thingy is the robot and the 3 transparent circles are supposed to be its sensors.

Now I want to be able to get the color data of the center pixels of those 3 transparent circles. Because I want to know if those three "sensors" are "sensing" either the red line or the white background. But for the life of me I can't figure out how to do that.

I found this code here on stackoverflow (modified it a bit to fit my project):

```
extension SKTexture {
    func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> SKColor {

        let pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.CGImage))
        var data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size().width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

        let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

        return SKColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

But when I call that function I get:

```
2015-06-22 02:47:04.012 SKTryout[16325:1119579] -[SKTexture CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080001c0690
2015-06-22 02:47:04.016 SKTryout[16325:1119579] -[SKTexture CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080001c0690
2015-06-22 02:47:04.054 SKTryout[16325:1119579] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88cec03c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff81f0e76e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88cef0ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88c34e24 ___forwarding___ + 1028
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88c34998 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   SKTryout                            0x0000000100003669 _TFE8SKTryoutCSo9SKTexture13getPixelColorfS0_FVSC7CGPointCSo7NSColor + 57
    6   SKTryout                            0x0000000100003a86 _TToFE8SKTryoutCSo9SKTexture13getPixelColorfS0_FVSC7CGPointCSo7NSColor + 54
    7   SKTryout                            0x000000010000139c _TFC8SKTryout9GameScene7keyDownfS0_FCSo7NSEventT_ + 444
    8   SKTryout                            0x00000001000013fa _TToFC8SKTryout9GameScene7keyDownfS0_FCSo7NSEventT_ + 58
    9   SpriteKit                           0x0000000100041fc4 -[SKView keyDown:] + 67
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ea0e11b -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 5452
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e39fd76 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 470
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e39c9b1 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4199
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e2c5c68 -[NSApplication run] + 711
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e242354 NSApplicationMain + 1832
    15  SKTryout                            0x0000000100002ef7 main + 87
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff84bf35c9 start + 1
```

Can anyone tell me what I should be doing instead?

Btw, in case it matters, I'm doing this in XCode 7 (Beta) and Swift 2.

Answer (score 3):

The CGImage method was only introduced to SKTexture in iOS 9 / OS X 10.11. You are not running OS X 10.11 — you're still back at OS X 10.10 — so this method does not exist on your machine.

Comment: The best solution, however, in my view, would be: don't try to "sense" anything. You know where the red line is, and you know where the "sensors" are. So just use that knowledge to determine whether they overlap. For example, if the red line is constructed by filling a CGPath, you can ask whether a certain point — the center of a "sensor" — is contained by that path.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, that helps a lot. I would still prefer to "sense" it, because I'd like to be able (later) to replace the background with any random png of a line whenever I please. This current background is also a png image btw.

Comment: This means that the `texture` property is not properly annotated in the headers as "available since 10.11", otherwise the Xcode 7 compiler should warn (or even error) when using it with a 10.10 deployment target.

Comment: @MartinR I wondered about that too: why didn't the compiler stop him dead in his tracks?

Comment: @Evert I thought you'd say that. I was just trying to provide an alternative plan... :)

Comment: @matt I appreciate that. :-)
Would you still have a suggestion for how to actually sense it?

Comment: Without the CGImage method you will need to resort to the image from which the texture comes, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with this:

```
func getPixelColor(name: String, pos: CGPoint) -> SKColor? {
    guard let img = NSImage(named: name) else {return nil}

    var pointer = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: img.size)

    guard let pixel = img.CGImageForProposedRect(&pointer, context: nil, hints: nil) else {return nil}

    let pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(pixel.takeRetainedValue()))
    let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

    let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(img.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

    let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+0]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

    return SKColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
}
```